# Live coding in WordPress

Tags: plugins, code

Is there a plugin or an easy way to integrate code writing and compilation windows in WordPress, for example to duplicate the [Learn Python functionality (see at bottom)](http://www.learnpython.org/).

Comment: This is an interesting question but have you tried to do any research before asking it? I went to the link you provided and it looks easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but would you care to elaborate? You suggest to add the ideone snippet to Wordpress? Thanks

Comment: I don't actually understand what are you trying to do. you need to give more specific details on what you are actually trying to do and what have you tried so far. Otherwise the answer is "No, but it should be easy to do", which will not help you or anybody else.

Comment: Asking for plugin is an off-topic here. [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @Vladtn, *you are the one* who needs to elaborate. What is `ideone snippet`? How is that compilation window created? I doubt there is a plugin and asking for recommendations is *off-topic*. If you want help building your solution, we need *much more* material.

Comment: StackExchange dragons scaring off beginners, sorry I asked. For info there seems to be a plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/run-this/ . And asking for best practices and administration seems to be part of the aim of this stack. Anyway, the question is simple enough.

Comment: Well, I hope you didn't get scared :) But having quality Q&A's is a basic rule of the Stack, in *any* of its sites. See what the dragon master thinks about this kind of Q: [Programming Is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html)